# Checkstyle check failure. How to write doc for param List<? extends T> recordList?

Tags: java, javadoc, checkstyle

CheckStyle not passed.
The error message is :
Type Javadoc comment is missing an @param  tag. [JavadocType]

```
    /**
     * @param List<? extends T> recordList
     */
    @InsertProvider(type = OracleBatchInsertProvider.class, method = "dynamicSQL")
    void batchInsert(List<? extends T> recordList);
```

Answer (score 3):

Omit the type, it is not expected after `@param`

The correct syntax is:

```
@param recordlist information on this param
```